# Invalid Identifier When Trying to Use Package Function in Summation Expression

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to use the sum function with a package function but running into an "invalid identifier" bug. Here's some example code with the error causing function commented

```
create or replace type numType as object
(
  myNum number
)
;
/ 
create or replace type numTypes is table of numType;
/
create or replace package testNumberPackage as
  function ReturnNum(in_numType numType) return number;
end;
/
create or replace package body testNumberPackage as
  function ReturnNum(in_numType numType) return number is
  begin
    return in_numType.myNum;
  end;
end;
/
declare l_numTypes numTypes; 
  l_count number; 
begin 
  l_numTypes := numTypes();
  for i in 1 .. 100 loop 
    l_numTypes.extend(1); 
    l_numTypes(l_numTypes.last) := numType(i); 
  end loop;

  select sum(n.myNum) into l_count from table(l_numTypes) n;
  select sum(testNumberPackage.ReturnNum(n)) into l_count from table(l_numTypes) n; --causes the error

  dbms_output.put_line(l_count); 
end;
/
```

The exact error for this code is

```
ORA-06550: line 11, column 42
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "N": invalid identifier
ORA-6550:  line 11, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that you can't pass a table into a parameter by using its alias. It doesn't even make sense to try doing that.

The next issue is how to get the column `mynum` that is returned from the `table(l_numTypes)` into the correct format to pass into `testNumberPackage.ReturnNum`, since it's of NUMBER datatype, and the function is expecting a numtype parameter.

To do that, you need to pass in an object with that column, like so: `numtype(n.mynum)`.

The following works for me:

```
declare
  l_numTypes numTypes; 
  l_count number; 
begin 
  l_numTypes := numTypes();
  for i in 1 .. 100 loop 
    l_numTypes.extend(1); 
    l_numTypes(l_numTypes.last) := numType(i); 
  end loop;

  select sum(n.myNum) into l_count from table(l_numTypes) n;
  select sum(testNumberPackage.ReturnNum(numtype(n.mynum))) into l_count from table(l_numTypes) n; --causes the error

  dbms_output.put_line(l_count); 
end;
/

5050
```

Clear as mud?

Comment: This works on this case but it's a bit difficult to always be re-constructing the type when the type may have dozens of attributes. Is there no way to use the numtype that's already stored in the l_numTypes table?

Comment: Why would you need to use the numtype at all? By doing table(l_numtypes), you've basically converted the array into a table, which has columns as defined by the record/object the array is based on. You've skipped the need to refer to the record type at all. I think you may be overthinking things? Why not just refer to the mynum column directly, as you did in the previous select statement?

Comment: In this case the testNumberPackage.ReturnNum function isn't doing much with the passed in object, but you can imagine a situation where a function would be passed an object and use lots of that objects attributes or functions to do a complex calculation.

Comment: In which case, why bother using a sql statement? Just use PL/ SQL

Comment: I was under the impression that by using a summation function there would be a performance boost. Is it not the case that using an sql statement to do many calculations would be faster than a for loop?

Comment: SQL is primarily designed to work against data stored in physical tables. It's typically faster to use SQL to process such data because a) the built-in functions have been designed to be efficient and b) using PL/SQL to process the data involves context switching between the SQL and PL/SQL engines. Something that lives in a PL/SQL structure is probably going to be faster to process in PL/SQL. You'd have to test for your scenario though.

Comment: Interesting. I just did a timing test on a million items. By using the sum function I get a timing result of 3.701 seconds, using a for loop I see it goes at 1.329 seconds. Thanks for the info on all this stuff, in future I'll try and keep my sql and plsql apart!

Comment: Were you testing the select statement that wasn't calling the packaged function, or the one that was? I'd expect the latter to be slower than the former.

Comment: I was testing the first one that doesn't use the package.

Comment: Ok, thanks; I was just curious! *{:-) Where does the data you're storing in the array come from? If it's from one or more tables, it'd be quicker to process the data directly from there using SQL (which I'm sure you'd already gathered!).

Comment: Ah that's true. In this case it's coming from a local nested table, if I run into the same problem with loading from a table I'll look into figuring it out with that scenario.